# When data is collected on different parts of the body, is the body part considered a within or between subject factor?

Tags: anova, repeated-measures

For a study I'm planning, I measure a property of vertebrae of subjects with a particular condition, and those without it. For each subject in this study, I measure that property on three different vertabrae. Also, I will use two different methods to measure this property. I'm interested in knowing whether this property is different in people with the disease and without it, as well as understanding differences based on which vertebra measured and which method was used to measure it.

I understand that I should use 3 factor mixed model ANOVA to analyze this data, where the 3 factors are group (diseased vs control), vertebra (L1, L3 or L5), and method of measuring (method 1 or method 2). I know that group is a between subjects factor, and method of measuring is a within subjects factor. Is vertebra a between subjects or within subjects factor?

Comment: Since a mixed model ANOVA assumes sphericity of the covariance matrix, I think you might do better with a multilevel model, which makes fewer assumptions.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about that option. It looks like a good approach. Thanks!